# mysql_real_escape_string() -> stripslashes() -> jquery.append()

Tags: php, jquery

im letting my users type in texts, then take them to server side php and process them, and if everything goes as it should, i just append the text with jquery without the page having to load all over again.

This is the procedure:

```
$post_text = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_text']));
```

some logic...

everything ok!

```
stripslashes(str_replace("\\n", "", $post_text))
```

and then i send all the nessesary data witj json

```
echo json_encode($return);
```

on the client side i append the html chunk saved in a variable from the server side.

this seems to work on localhost, it removes all the slashes and so on, but online it just doenst remove the slashes, and they keep coming up, when i hit refresh they dissapear becouse then its a

```
stripslashes($comment['statusmsg_text'])
```

written out with php straight from the database. Is it the json that adds some extra stuff? i dont get it becouse it works perfectly on localhost.

best of regards,
alexander

Comment: It sounds like you're using `htmlspecialchars()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` without actually understanding what they *do*...

Comment: you should swap `mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['post_text'],ENT_QUOTES));` as function work from the inside out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be, that on your server and your localhost the [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) directive is set differently, so your string is double encoded on server side.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i did a magic_quotes_gpc right now and it was enabled. I cant turn it off tho =/

Answer (score 3):

The additional slashes might be [magic quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes). You [shouldn’t rely on them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.whynot) and [disable them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling).

Additionally, `mysql_real_escape_string` should only be used to prepare strings to be put into a string context in an MySQL statement. Similar applies to `htmlspecialchars` that should only be used for sanitizing data to be put into an HTML context.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without `stripslashes`, `json_encode` should handle that. All you need to do is use `mysql_real_escape` once, before your string touches your database.